# How to remove a Teams BOT from a call

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

We are using a BOT to manage connecting Teams Call legs together, and removing them from the call.

It is possible to remove a call leg/participant from a call using

```
ICall.Participants[participantID].DeleteAsync()
```

by specifying the participant ID for that call leg.

What we would like to do is to get the BOT to remove itself from the call. However, no participant ID is generated for the BOT.

Is it possible for the BOT to remove itself from a call ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Delete Call actually removes the associated call leg only, if the call is a group call. In this case it removes the BOT from the call, leaving the other participants still connected.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/call-delete?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

```
ICall.DeleteAsync()
```